# Problemas com versão do MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Na empresa onde eu trabalho, o desenvolvimento do front é completamente separado do back. Portanto, os desenvolvedores front não possuem Visual Studio instalado e dependem dos devs .Net pra buildarem e subirem as DLLs para que eles possam baixar e poder rodar as aplicações nas máquinas locais.

Com esse cenário, estamos planejando instalar apenas o Build Tools pra restaurar os pacotes Nuget e buildar os códigos C#. Porém, estou com dificuldades com o MSBuild.

O comando que estou utlizando é:
`msbuild SOLUTION.sln /p:Configuration="Release"`

Porém, recebo alguns erros no processo de build:
`error CS1056: Caractere '$' inesperado`
`error CS1041: Identificador esperado. 'static' é uma palavra-chave`
`error CS1518: Class, delegate, enum, interface ou struct esperado`
Alguns outros erros acontecem. Buildando diretamente no Visual Studio, esse problema não acontece.

Já verifiquei a versão do .Net Framework instalado:
`Microsoft (R) Versão do Mecanismo de Compilação 4.7.3190.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Versão 4.0.30319.42000]`

Ao tentar instalar a versão 4.7 do .Net Framework, o instalador informa que já possui outra superior instalada.

Tentei verificar o ToolsVersion do MSBuild, mas a única versão disponível é a "4.0":
`MSBUILD : error MSB1040: ToolsVersion inválido. A versão das ferramentas "15.0" não é reconhecida. As versões de ferramentas disponíveis são "4.0".`

Como eu consigo realizar esse processo? A restauração dos pacotes Nugets está funcionando perfeitamente, porém o processo de build está com esses problemas.

Comment: Primeira pergunta, se o front é totalmente separado do back, por que diabos eles precisam de alguma dll ou package do nuget do back? Vocês não deveriam estar entregando Web APIs para eles?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo a nossa equipe de front trabalha apenas com HTML e CSS. Qualquer coisa além disso, entra como "backend". Eles precisam rodar a aplicação (desenvolvemos em um CMS) para ver as alterações que eles fizeram.

Comment: Adicione a instrução para utilizar a versão específica que você tem disponível então, o build pelo VS ele builda? Dê uma olhada aqui https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/overriding-toolsversion-settings?view=vs-2015

Comment: @LeandroAngelo a única versão disponível para utilizar no ToolsVersion é a 4.0. Vi em outros links para testar com a versão 14 ou 15, mas não está disponível.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui disponibilizar a versão 12.0 instalando o MSBuild Tools 2013: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

Porém, ao buildar com a versão 12.0, recebo mensagens de erro informando que não foi possível encontrar os arquivos .csproj.metaproj e eles realmente não existem, mas não são gerados.
A solution é carregada normalmente pelo Visual Studio e não gera esses arquivos.